# Condition in Redshift window function

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to identify the activation event for each user from a table with columns `user_id`, `received_at` and `event_name` . To get the first event I can use the following window function:

```
first_value(e.received_at ignore nulls) 
over (partition by e.user_id 
order by e.received_at rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) 
as first_event
```

I'm trying to get just the events with a certain name, in a subselect I could do something like

```
MIN(
 CASE WHEN
 e.event_name = 'User Activated'
THEN e.received_at
ELSE NULL END
) AS user_activated
```

Is it possible to add a condition like this to a window function?

Comment: why not, have you tried that?
`first_value(case when e.event_name = 'User Activated' then e.received_at end ignore nulls)`

Comment: @AlexYes you're absolutely right. Sorry for asking a dumb question, still wrapping my head around this. Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions allow not just the column but any expression as parameter, so you can easily use `CASE` there:

```
first_value(case 
    when e.event_name = 'User Activated' 
    then e.received_at 
    end 
ignore nulls)
over (
    partition by e.user_id 
    order by e.received_at 
    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) 
as first_event
```